# How to register custom service chain element

Tags: service, registration, intershop

We are trying to implement our custom service chain element (like LogHandler) with cookbook: https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2329T4#Cookbook-ManagedServiceFramework-Recipe:AddChainElements

At end of cookbook there is a sentence about registering custom chain element with service manager:

> Last but not least, the handler must be registered so it can be found according to its ID.
>
> This is done via the registerChainElement( ID, Class) method of the ServiceMgr.

The problem is that we don't know where to add call to registerChainElement method? I suppose that has to be executed on server start or on service registration?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in method "Cartridge.onReadyHook()" of your Cartridge class.